# javascript Math.atan( Math.tan() ) useless?

Tags: javascript, math

On windows 7, look at the file

> c:\windows\winsxs...\weather.js

There is a function `computeSunRiseSunSet(Latitude, Longitude, TimeZone, Year, Month, Day)`.

They don't cite the source of the algorithm.

One line of code is

```
var C2=RD*(Math.atan(Math.tan(L0+C)) - Math.atan(.9175*Math.tan(L0+C))-C);
```

Why is there Math.atan( Math.tan( L0+C )) ?

Is it the same as ( L0+C ) or there are corner cases ?

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript?

Comment: Also, doing `atan(tan(...))` will constrain the angle between -pi/2 and +pi/2. Whether that's the purpose I don't know, there's probably a less weird way to do that.

Comment: it's a precision issue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`atan(tan(x))` is a periodic "sawtooth" function:

```
for -pi/2 < x < pi/2,   atan(tan(x)) = x
for  pi/2 < x < 3pi/2,  atan(tan(x)) = x - pi
for 3pi/2 < x < 5pi/2,  atan(tan(x)) = x - 2pi
...
```

You can [plot it and see other details about it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan%28tan%28x%29%29) on Wolfram Alpha.